# Sort multidimensional array by pairs

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array by pairs. I know I can use a `Comparator`, but I want to achieve that with my code. Here is what I tried so far:

```
 private static void sortArr(int[][] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        int maxValColumnIndex0 = arr[i][0];
        int maxValColumnIndex1 = arr[i][1];
        int maxIndex = i;

        for (int column = i + 1; column < arr[i].length; column++) {
            if (maxValColumnIndex1 < arr[column][1]){
                maxValColumnIndex1 = arr[column][1];
                maxValColumnIndex0 = arr[column][0];
                maxIndex = column;
            }
            if (i != maxIndex){
                arr[maxIndex][0] = arr[i][0];
                arr[maxIndex][1] = arr[i][1];
                arr[i][0] = maxValColumnIndex0;
                arr[i][1] = maxValColumnIndex1;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Sample input:

```
{{4, 2}, {1, 7}, {4, 5}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {4, 1}}
```

The output should be like:

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 7}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 5}}
```

What I already get:

```
{{1, 7}, {4, 2}, {4, 5}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {4, 1}}`
```

How to sort that array by pair?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to see where your logic goes wrong?

Comment: @assylias yes, but unfortunately i can't analyise how to make it work!

Comment: Whether or not you use the `Comparator` interface, you should _definitely_ separate your sorting and comparing logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to sort them as `pairs` as you said. Here's modified bubble sort, to work with your example:

```
 private static void sortArr(int[][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < arr.length - 1; column++) {
            if(arr[column][0] > arr[column + 1][0]) {
                swap(arr, column);
            } else if(arr[column][0] == arr[column + 1][0] && arr[column][1] > arr[column + 1][1]) {
                    swap(arr, column);
            }
        }
    }

}

private static void swap(int[][] arr, int column) {
    int[] temp = arr[column];
    arr[column] = arr[column + 1];
    arr[column + 1] = temp;
}
```

The result is as you want : `[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 7], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 5]]`